# Team Foundation Server 2010 and Team Foundation Build Server 2010 SP1 compatability

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Is it OK to install TFS 2010 SP1 only in the build server and not in the actual Team Foundation Server?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. We have kept the compatibility between the build service and the TFS server for 2010 RTM and SP1, so it should work fine. Honestly, I don't remember if we guaranteed that we would keep compatibility in this scenario, so it is still recommended to bring both to the same version.

In general, for major releases such as TFS 2010 and TFS 2008, we ask the build service and the TFS server to be installed with the same version, which means if you upgrade one you should upgrade the other as well.